# How did tôt shift from denoting « chaudement » to « promptement »?

Tags: étymologie

I don't understand the emboldening from [CNTRL](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/t%C3%B4t). How does « chaudement » semantically appertain to « promptement »?

> Du lat. pop. *tostum*, neutre prés. adv. de *tostus* « grillé, rôti, brûlé », part. passé de *torrere* « griller, rôtir »; *tostum* a dû signifier d'abord « chaudement » d'où « promptement ».

*Word Origins* (2005 2e) by John Ayto. p 510 Left column.

> #### toast [14]

> *Toast* comes via Old French *toster*
> ‘roast, grill’ from Vulgar Latin **tostāre*, a
> derivative of the past participle of Latin *torrēre*
> ‘parch’ (source of English *torrid*). Its use as a
> noun, meaning ‘toasted bread’, dates from the
> 15th century. It was common to put sippets or
> croutons of spiced toast into drinks to improve
> their flavour, and it was the custom of gallants in
> the 17th century, when (as they frequently did)
> they drank the health of ladies, to say that the
> name of the lady in question enhanced the
> flavour of their drink better than any toast. That
> is supposedly the origin of the use of the term
> *toast* for ‘drinking someone’s health’.

Answer (score 3):

Littré's definition adds some more details, but is still unclear:

> du latin tostus,
> brûlé, par assimilation de la rapidité de la flamme ; c'est ainsi que,
> dans l'ancien français, on a dit chaut pas, pour rapidement ; que
> Dante a dit impresa tosta, entreprise rapide(...)

So *Tostus* means burnt/toasted, hence cooked fast and strong. Something done swiftly gets  finished early, so I guess this how we get to the final meaning.

It seems not perfectly consistent with the example : if *"chaut pas"* (hot step) means walking fast, then *"chaut/chaud"* means fast and *tostus* must be "very fast". And there's no obvious link between the *rapidité de la flamme* and "*chaut pas*".

The shift between fast and early is not totally satisfying either, but I can imagine a  sentence like this:

> Cette tâche doit être terminée aussi vite que possible.

> This task shall be finished as quickly as possible.

shifting over time to mean:

> Cette tâche doit être terminée aussi tôt que possible.

> That task shall be finished as early as possible.

I'm not a linguist, though.